# How to merge multiple columns of a dataframe using regex？

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` which as following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'number_C1_E1': ['1', '2', None, None, '5', '6', '7', '8'],
     'fruit_C11_E1': ['apple', 'banana', None, None, 'watermelon', 'peach', 'orange', 'lemon'],
     'name_C111_E1': ['tom', 'jerry', None, None, 'paul', 'edward', 'reggie', 'nicholas'],
     'number_C2_E2': [None, None, '3', None, None, None, None, None],
     'fruit_C22_E2': [None, None, 'blueberry', None, None, None, None, None],
     'name_C222_E2': [None, None, 'anthony', None, None, None, None, None],
     'number_C3_E1': [None, None, '3', '4', None, None, None, None],
     'fruit_C33_E1': [None, None, 'blueberry', 'strawberry', None, None, None, None],
     'name_C333_E1': [None, None, 'anthony', 'terry', None, None, None, None],
     }
)
```

Here what I want to do is combine those columns and we have two rules:

1. If a column removes `_C{0~9}` or `_C{0~9}{0~9}` or `_C{0~9}{0~9}{0~9}` is equal to another column, these two columns can be combined.

> Let's take `number_C1_E1` `number_C2_E2` `number_C3_E1` as an example, here `number_C1_E1` and `number_C3_E1` can be combined because they are both `number_E1` after `removing _C{0~9}`.

2. The two combined columns should get rid of the `None` values.

The desired result is

```
  number_C1_1_E1 fruit_C11_1_E1 name_C111_1_E1 number_C2_1_E2 fruit_C22_1_E2 name_C222_1_E2
0              1          apple            tom           None           None           None
1              2         banana          jerry           None           None           None
2              3      blueberry        anthony              3      blueberry        anthony
3              4     strawberry          terry           None           None           None
4              5     watermelon           paul           None           None           None
5              6          peach         edward           None           None           None
6              7         orange         reggie           None           None           None
7              8          lemon       nicholas           None           None           None
```

Anyone has a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same as your previous question, but also compute a renamer for your columns:

```
group = df.columns.str.replace(r'_C\d+', '', regex=True)

names = df.columns.to_series().groupby(group).first()

out = (df.groupby(group, axis=1, sort=False).first()
         .rename(columns=names)
       )
```

Alternative:

```
group = df.columns.str.replace(r'_C\d+', '', regex=True)

out = (df.groupby(group, axis=1, sort=False).first()
         .set_axis(df.columns[~group.duplicated()], axis=1)
       )
```

Output:

```
  number_C1_E1 fruit_C11_E1 name_C111_E1 number_C2_E2 fruit_C22_E2 name_C222_E2
0            1        apple          tom         None         None         None
1            2       banana        jerry         None         None         None
2            3    blueberry      anthony            3    blueberry      anthony
3            4   strawberry        terry         None         None         None
4            5   watermelon         paul         None         None         None
5            6        peach       edward         None         None         None
6            7       orange       reggie         None         None         None
7            8        lemon     nicholas         None         None         None
```

Answer (score 2):

This builds on @mozway's idea, and tries to avoid a double groupby:

```py
box = df.columns.str.split(r"C\d+", expand=True)
box = df.groupby(box, axis=1)
columns = [grp.columns[0] for _, grp in box]
frame = box.first()
frame.columns = columns
frame
  fruit_C11_E1 fruit_C22_E2 name_C111_E1 name_C222_E2 number_C1_E1 number_C2_E2
0        apple         None          tom         None            1         None
1       banana         None        jerry         None            2         None
2    blueberry    blueberry      anthony      anthony            3            3
3   strawberry         None        terry         None            4         None
4   watermelon         None         paul         None            5         None
5        peach         None       edward         None            6         None
6       orange         None       reggie         None            7         None
7        lemon         None     nicholas         None            8         None
```

Comment: split and list comprehension are also expensive ;) Actually a simple slicing of the non duplicated columns names based on the groups is sufficient (see my update)